# Only half of the data of dbf is converted to xls

Tags: c#, excel

Hello im trying to convert the dbf to xls but the problem is only half of the data is converted. Can someone help me and find what is the problem here?

Here is sample picture of dbf that i will convert.
[image]

here is the converted file only 2 data
[image]

**UPDATE**
Here is another sample as requested.

i convert this dbf file.
[image]

this is the result
[image]

here's the code.

```
  static Missing mv = Missing.Value;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
            if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
            {
                textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;



            }
        }

 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constr = "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=" + Directory.GetParent(textBox1.Text).FullName;
            string ExcelFileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(textBox1.Text) + ".xls";
            using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr))
            {
                var sql = "select * from " + Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text) + ";";
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Error connecting database: " + ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                    return;
                }
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    MessageBox.Show("Reading database...  ", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    MessageBox.Show("Completed.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        con.Close();
                    }
                    catch { }
                }

                if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    GenerateExcel(dt, ExcelFileName);
                }
            }

        }

static void GenerateExcel(DataTable sourceDataTable, string ExcelFileName)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Generating Excel File...", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);


            Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook wkb = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(mv);
            Excel.Worksheet wks = wkb.Sheets[1];

            for (int i = 0; i < sourceDataTable.Columns.Count; ++i)
            {
                ((Excel.Range)wks.Cells[1, i + 1]).Value = sourceDataTable.Columns[i].ColumnName;
            }
            Excel.Range header = wks.get_Range((object)wks.Cells[1, 1], (object)wks.Cells[1, sourceDataTable.Columns.Count]);
            header.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@";

            object[,] sourceDataTableObjectArray = new object[sourceDataTable.Rows.Count, sourceDataTable.Columns.Count];
            for (int row = 0; row < sourceDataTable.Rows.Count; ++row)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < sourceDataTable.Columns.Count; ++col)
                {
                    sourceDataTableObjectArray[row, col] = sourceDataTable.Rows[row][col].ToString();
                }
            }
            ((Excel.Range)wks.get_Range((object)wks.Cells[2, 1], (object)wks.Cells[sourceDataTable.Rows.Count, sourceDataTable.Columns.Count])).Value2 = sourceDataTableObjectArray;
            header.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
            header.Font.Bold = true;
            wks.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 1;
            wks.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
            wks.SaveAs(ExcelFileName, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8, mv, mv, mv, mv, mv, mv, mv, mv);
            wks = null;
            wkb = null;
            excelApp.Quit();
            MessageBox.Show("Completed.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code looks good. You could add some logging so you know at which point you "lose" those rows. Example: using System.Diagnostics; Debug.WriteLine("dt has <" + dt.Rows.Count + "> rows at this point");

Comment: @Ulli Schmid dont know what to do :(

Comment: If I look at the data in the top screenshot, it's obvious which data isn't coming through. Are you sure that data in the top 7 lines is of interest? Maybe it's just table header data that you don't need in the output?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i test to convert many dbf sir. But the result some of it are missing the last data and some is only half. :3

Comment: @nethken some more examples might help us to find a pattern - could you show us 1 or two more files with the problem?

Comment: @UlliSchmid sure bro wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue that explains why the last row keeps getting deleted:

```
((Excel.Range)wks.get_Range((object)wks.Cells[2, 1], (object)wks.Cells[sourceDataTable.Rows.Count, sourceDataTable.Columns.Count])).Value2 = sourceDataTableObjectArray;
```

should be changed to

```
((Excel.Range)wks.get_Range((object)wks.Cells[2, 1], (object)wks.Cells[sourceDataTable.Rows.Count + 1, sourceDataTable.Columns.Count])).Value2 = sourceDataTableObjectArray;
```

Explanation: The Excel range is not large enough (1 too small) to accept the full  sourceDataTable.

***As for the other issues*** (seen in example 1) - the problem lies in the database. Your "missing" data is not included in your database query return, because those rows are flagged as "deleted" in the .dbf files. This source:

[Manipulate the 'deleted record' flag on DBF files](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b504a667-9208-4f86-afa2-4f4ac4f60159/manipulate-the-deleted-record-flag-on-dbf-files?forum=sqldataaccess)

leads me to believe that you may solve your problems by changing

```
var sql = "select * from " + Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text) + ";";
```

to

```
string tableName = Path.GetFileName(textBox1.Text)
var sql = "select * from Deleted(" + tableName + ") UNION select * from " + tableName + ";";
```

I am really no expert on your dbf database and sql queries, if this doesn't work you should post this as a new question.

Comment: What exactly is the output if you are logging?

Comment: I convert a dbf file with 27 rows. and then the output is "dt has<7> rows at point 1. sourceDataTable has<7> rows at point 2

Comment: thanks, that narrows the problem down. In the excel file you can then only see 7 rows + 1 headrow, right?

Comment: what do u mean headrow sir?

Comment: Sir i update my question i add another sample. Total row is 14 in dbf and add the header the overall total is 15 but in excel the row is only 14 with header included. I think the problem is in the header? What do you think sir?

Comment: I found one error that solves at least part of your problems - I will put it in the answer above.

Comment: I'm sorry but the rest of the problem is not part of your code. The other missing rows seem to be metadata or header data, or something similar. Do you really need them?

Comment: Yess i need them all.

Comment: Well, you seem nice, and I have nothing to do. Could you send me the .dbf file? (the first one with the A A A B B B A A A rows)

Comment: how can i send to you?

Comment: Is it sensitive data? If not, you can upload it somewhere like http://www.file-upload.net/

Comment: Can i send it to your email?

Comment: i send it to you sir. but i dont know what is .cdx file.

Comment: Thats a different file. Please send me the one you used in the first example.

Comment: what will you do by the way?

Comment: I examined the .dbf file and updated the answer above.

Comment: Yeah i notice the black thing in the side. I think's that's the problem sir. Thank you for all your efforts! :) Wish me luck lol.

Comment: I accept your answer because it solved the problem of not getting the last data.

Comment: I'm sure you'll solve the rest of the issue with ease. Good luck ;)